# Sitecore core database - How to add a new template

Tags: sitecore

I need to make a new template in Core database to create some configuration items. 
By default you can not add a "New template" to templates/System... section.

How can I add a new template to core database?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click the location you want to create your template, click Insert From -> select Template (or Standard Template if that's what you want)
You can find this in `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template`.

By the way, it's not generally recommended to add your template to the System folder. Might be better to add it to either a new folder or the User Defined folder.

Comment: Thanks, When I add a new template, if I try to add a new "data" section, and save it, it does not get saved. In the Inheritance tab it gives this error, "An instance of Sitecore.Data.Templates.Template was null. Additional information: Template "{3DAC5127-D5E1-473C-A4BA-468F32CE5CAC}" not found ". Is this because this is not in the Master database?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why the Inheritance tab gives that exception, but if I go to the Standard Template in the /sitecore/templates/System/Templates folder it gives me the same exception. I do get a bit of a different message than you, I get "System.InvalidOperationException: fieldTypeItem"

Answer (score 0):

By right clicking Templates >> System folder select Insert >> Insert from Template option in the popup menu.

Select `/sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template` as [Trayek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064919/trayek) suggests.

Added Data in the Builder tab and Inheritance tab also works fine. (Screen shot below)

[image]